# Error when setting CRS with Rasterio in python

Tags: python, coordinates, rasterio, proj

I'm testing out rasterio for a project, but get some errors regarding CRS.
I get this error:

`File "rasterio\crs.pyx", line 590, in rasterio.crs.CRS.from_epsg`

`rasterio.errors.CRSError: The EPSG code is unknown. PROJ: proj_create_from_database: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\share\contrib\postgis-3.2\proj\proj.db contains DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR = 0 whereas a number >= 2 is expected. It comes from another PROJ installation.`

I have searched around the internet for a while, but I can't really find a good solution.
What do I need to do here, and what is the best or easiest fix?

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my problem:

- Uninstall PostGIS
- Remove PROJ_LIB from environment variables
- Restart program